# Prevent private post 404

Tags: templates, private

I want private posts (for those *not* logged in) to use the `single.php` template just as public posts do, at the moment they get thrown over to the `404.php` template.

I've had a good look through the core files but I cannot find where the template change (note: this is not a redirect) happens.

Can anyone help?

**Edit**

To explain why I want this, I want all visitors to see a preview of the content, but logged in "members" to see the entire post content.

Comment: Have you done the usual rigamarole (disable plugins, switch to default theme) to see if the `404` theme load is coming from somewhere other than WP core?

Comment: I don't have any plugins installed, this is default functionality. I just want to disable this default functionality so private posts (for those who aren't logged in) shows the `single.php` template.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Content Visibility](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Private_Content) page, Private posts are visible *only* to those with sufficient permission levels.  WordPress doesn't expose them to non-logged-in users at all, hence (presumably) the `404`.

If you want to display a limited preview to non-members, instead of setting the post to **Private**, you could try something like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse101968_preview' );
function wpse101968_preview( $content ) {
    if( is_single() ) {
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $content = get_the_excerpt();
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

And then your non-logged-in visitors will see the post's excerpt instead of the entire post.  You can customize the excerpts, too, so that they see only what you *want* them to see.

#### References

Codex:

- [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)
- [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt)

Comment: +1 modifying public content to fit requirements would be more robust than hacking up private content to be non-private

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing a redirect, to confirm your own observation, so much as you are seeing just what it looks like-- a "File Not Found". Take a look at [the query in the source around line 2438 (among others)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/query.php#L2438). The status of the post is part of the query itself, so if the status doesn't match then no posts are found and that means `404`. As you can see from the code, `status` is pretty rigidly protected. That is proving difficult to override.

I'd recommend using a custom post type for you "logged in only" posts. That is going to be much easier to control both on the front end and the back end.

Answer (score 0):

How do you set password protected posts to be viewed by logged-out users?  We created the functionality and all logged-out users are getting a 404 after inserting the password.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/270322)