# Show a special message for private page?

Tags: plugins, pages, 404-error, private

If I set a page to private, can I have it show a message instead of a 404 page for public users?

Comment: I have in the past ([due to another question here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101981/21376)) attempted to get around the `'private' == 404` result and so far have not been able to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is challenging, because showing *something* would require page not to be private.

It is more common to leave page public, but make it produce conditional output depending on if user is logged ([`is_user_logged_in()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_user_logged_in/)) in or other criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rarst. Unless you use conditional output you'll need to figure out how to undo what the Core does with urls for Posts that are private. Otherwise a user that is not logged in will get the 404.

Going with `is_user_logged_in()` will take care of what you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
if ( current_user_can('read_private_pages') )
```

With this condition, only Administrators and Editors can view the content of the page.