# Override private status - Enable users to read private posts

Tags: 404-error, post-status, private

**Hidden private posts for not logged in users**

The private posts are by default only visible when logged in.

**Override, show private posts for everyone**

Is there a clever way to override this? Make it visible to everyone?

**404 page**

I know about using it in queries but the big problem is the 404 page that is shown. Instead of 404 template it should use single.php template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent private post 404](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101968/prevent-private-post-404)

Comment: The whole point of making a post private is to prevent not logged in users (including robots) from having access to it (preventing indexing, actually). If you want to give full access to those posts just **don't make them private**. If you need to group them just add a *private* tag or put them in a category called *private*.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, private posts are private for a good reason.

If you want to change this behaviour, you could probably alter the [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) which is used to retrieve your posts.

I did not try it, but this could work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => array(
                         'publish',
                         'private'
                     )
);
$myposts = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add capability of reading private post to any user role like this.

Add these code below to functions.php in wordpress theme folder:

```
$subRole = get_role( 'author' );
$subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );
```

Here you'll see a details tutorial http://www.shartd.com/let-subscriber-see-private-post-wordpress/

Answer (score -1):

I'm confused by the answers.

When I have "private" posts/pages, *I cannot see them when I am logged in*. I can only see them when I am the Admin.

About the OP's question--

I use the WPDB class methods to extract post_content from the database selectively to bypass permissions:

```
global $wpdb; //global wpdb class may not work everywhere...
$post_id = (int) $post_id; // you supply $post_id && make sure int...
$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = $post_id");
if(!empty($result)) $result = apply_filters('the_content',$result); //will also execute shortcodes in the content
//do stuff like echo $result
```